# why output wait before execution instead of middle process in php?

Tags: php

```
for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++) { 
    echo $i ;
}    
sleep(2) ;  
for ($i=5; $i<=10; $i++) { 
    echo $i ;
}
```

I want first print 1 to 4 than wait for 2 seconds and than print 5 to 10. this is working on [online php editor](http://www.writephponline.com/) but when i am trying on window(xampp) than it is showing 1 to 10 directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the online `PHP` is running it like it would in a shell so you can see the output as the code is run.

On your Xampp virtual machine Apache is waiting for the `PHP` script to be fully run before serving it up to your browser hence why it would seem like the `sleep()` command is not doing anything.

Run your script in the command line interface and you will see what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand difference between PHP command line and HTTP request.

If you execute your php command line then it will provide output in realistic manner.

```
your_root_folder$ php your_script.php
```

But if you execute php script by HTTP request then Apache is waiting for complete execution of whole script and then serve output to client.

```
http://localhost/your_script.php
```

As per your question, online PHP editor is posting your written code to their PHP server, executes your code in their server after complete execution server will gives output to you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answers already present, if you need to output immediately to the browser, you can use [ob_end_flush()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) and [flush()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php), i.e.:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++) {
    echo $i ;
}
ob_end_flush();
flush();
sleep(2) ;
for ($i=5; $i<=10; $i++) {
    echo $i ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You make a call to your server, the php script is run and when
this is fully completed, the result is returned to your browser.

you can try it for sleep.

```
<?php
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush(1);

for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++) { 
    echo $i ;
} 
for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) { 
    sleep(2);
    if(ob_get_level()>0)
       ob_end_flush(); 
}
for ($i=5; $i<=10; $i++) { 
    echo $i ;
}
?>
```